# Как отправить много данных через ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть 2 скрипта:
Первый берет данные из 2 форм и отправляет обработчику (фильтр)

```
$(document).on('change','.sort_order',function(){
   var url = "ajax/objects.php";
   var dataString = $("#search_form, #order-form").serialize();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: dataString,
     success: function(data)
     {                  
        $('.ajax_result').html(data);
     } ,
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }               
   }); 
});
```

Второй берет id ссылки и отправляет туда же (Постраничная навигация)

```
   $(document).on('click','.pag',function(){
   var url = "ajax/objects.php";
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
    var parent = $(this);
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: dataString,
     success: function(data)
     {                  
        $('.ajax_result').html(data);
     } ,
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }               
   }); 
});
```

Как объединить эти 2 скрипта в 1?
Чтоб скрипт отправлял данные из форм и id ссылки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `serialize` преобразует форму в строку вида: `key1=value1&key2=value2`

Следовательно, всё что вам нужно, это сложить две строки:

`dataString = $("#search_form, #order-form").serialize() + '&' + 'id='+ id`